# htaccess rewrite if file not exists in cache folder

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to check if file is not exist in the cache folder, than rewire it to a php file.

```
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/$0 !-f [NC]
    RewriteRule ^([^.]+\.(jpg|png|gif|css|js))$ include/cache/optimizer.php?file=$1&type=$2&c=$0 [L,QSA,NC]
```

eg1 : example.com/images/logo.jpg to check from example.com/cache/images/logo.jpg
eg2 : example.com/images/user/user1.jpg to check from example.com/cache/user/user1.jpg
eg3 : example.com/css/style.css to check from example.com/cache/css/style.css

Please help me in it.

thank you.

My htaccess code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# Admin area
RewriteRule ^admin(.*) admin$1 [L]



# Rule for compression images and scripts
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache%{REQUEST_URI} !-f [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^.]+\.(jpg|png|gif|css|js))$ include/cache/optimizer.php?file=$1&type=$2&c=$0 [L,QSA,NC]



# Check if file *.* exist in the cache foldel
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/$0 -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /cache/$0 [L]

# Check if file index.html  exist in the cache foldel
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/$0/index.html -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /cache/$0/index.html [L]




# Normal behave
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: My pleasure. well if file exists in the cache folder. its still rewriting to php file

Comment: Try this condition: `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache%{REQUEST_URI} !-f [NC]`

Comment: What is location of this .htaccess file? And are there other files also? If yes post complete .htaccess

Comment: Other rules in htaccess are working fine. it means that htaccess is placed correctly (in root folder). and images and css files are located respectively.

Comment: Right but order of rules matter here. I need to see all the .htaccess to see if this rule is getting executed in right order.

Comment: Please review my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove negative check `!` and make it positive:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] 

# Admin area 
RewriteRule ^admin(.*) admin$1 [L] 

# Check if file index.html exist in the cache foldel 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/$1/index.html -f [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /cache/$1/index.html [L] 

# Check if file *.* exist in the cache foldel 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/$1 -f [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /cache/$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^([^.]+\.(jpg|png|gif|css|js))$ include/cache/optimizer.php?file=$1&type=$2&c=$0 [L,QSA,NC] 

# Normal behave 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: if file or image not exists in cache folder. than rewrite it to php script. the php script optimize this image or minify the code and moved it to cache folder

Comment: Thank you so much. Its working exactly as I need. Thank you your time and helping again

Comment: Can you tell me what does these rules mean

Comment: this rule means **do nothing** of a files exists in cache already. As `RewriteRule ^ - [L]` means take no action and skip all following rules.

Comment: There is one problem: its not showing 404 error if file not exist in original folder :(

Comment: What is original folder here?

Comment: I need to step away from my computer for sometime, I will check back this thread tonight my time.

Comment: I mean if example.com/css/style.css is not exist here and also in cache folder. your script is rewriting to php if file not exists in cache. php will copy it from original path (requested path) and optimize it to cache folder

Comment: Its not checking in cache folder. its loading file from original path. because file exists in the original path

Comment: Can you help on skype ?

Comment: If a file exists in original folder and as well as in cache folder then which one you want to show?

Comment: I want to show cached file. if file not exists in cache that it should rewrite the original file to php script

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56815/discussion-between-anubhava-and-user3034390).