# apache htaccess mod_rewrite to check cache folder first then run WordPress index.php

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, caching

I am setting up a very simple cache for my own WordPress plugin... I have been researching this here on StackOverflow and elsewhere for a couple of days.  Found some great answers that were very close (looking for image files, etc), but none for this specific scenario - and modifying other solutions is not working.

I've got everything working except the rewrite rules to do the following:

Incoming request for either http / https

```
domain.com/page-slug/   OR  domain.com/year/month/page-slug/
```

Need htaccess to **first check the cache folder for**

```
domain.com/wp-content/cache/myfolder/page-slug.html
```

(please note the incoming request can be for "/page-slug/" OR "/page-slug"  and the cache file name has the ".html" extension to make it "page-slug.html")

If the cache file does *not* exist, **then just**

```
...go through the usual WordPress index.php process
```

Also -- what if there is no slug/page name in the url?

ie: the home page ...  can htaccess direct

```
domain.com  to  domain.com/wp-content/cache/myfolder/index.html
```

and if the cached index.html does not exist, go to the WP index.php

Is there a way to do the above cache checks purely with the .htaccess rules?  Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

( I hope my explanation above was clear -- I get confused myself!  LOL )

UPDATE:

I found a good answer in [htaccess rewrite if file not exists in cache folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24586809/htaccess-rewrite-if-file-not-exists-in-cache-folder) by anubhava and tried to modify it as follows, I think it is close, but its not quite working:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# Admin area 
RewriteRule ^admin(.*) admin$1 [L] 

# Check if file *.* exist in the cache foldel 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/ebg/$1 -f [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /cache/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the above solutions don't work, please contact your web host provider. Most likely you don't have Mod_Rewrite activated on your webhost package.

Comment: mod_rewrite is activated -- it works fine with WordPress, but the code above does not look at the cache for the slug + ".html"  -- I just don't know how to get it to do that - and then if the file is not there, go back to the default WordPress rewrite rules.