# How to use htacces to serve pre-rendered or call application

Tags: .htaccess, caching, cakephp, apache2.4, system-administration

I was using **.htaccess** to serve pre-rendered pages inside my **cache** dir otherwise the requests is redirected to my CakePHP application.

I have this structure in my public folder:

> /cache/
>   /index.php

Every request to my Application is rendered to the **cache** dir in the way that **/categoria/product-123123.html** is saved into **/cache/categoria/product-123123.html**, until here everything is ok, the problem is: now I want to serve **/cache/categoria/product-123123.html** for every requests to  **/categoria/product-123123.html**

Could someone explain to me how to use **.htaccess** to do that or other way.

Regards

Comment: Is your "cache" folder inside "webroot"? If so what you want will just work with the default URL rewriting rules in webroot/.htaccess.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [htaccess rewrite if file not exists in cache folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24586809/htaccess-rewrite-if-file-not-exists-in-cache-folder)